# esapi: for src attribute, shall we use encodeForHTMLAttribute? encodeForURL? or both?

Tags: coldfusion, xss, coldfusion-10, esapi

Which one's correct?

```
<img src="#encodeForHTMLAttribute(FORM.path)#">
```

or

```
<img src="#encodeForURL(FORM.path)#">
```

or

```
<img src="#encodeForHTMLAttribute(encodeForURL(FORM.path))#">
```

?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the method(s) which match the context of where you are inserting the text that needs encoding.

**encodeForUrl** is for placing dynamic text into a URL - so it will replace `/` with `%2F` ([and so on](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)), and if you apply it to an entire URL, you will have an encoded URL (which is therefore broken for use in a src attribute).

If you are allowing users to supply a partial URL, you would need to split on `/` (and any other relevant delimiters), apply encodeForUrl on each part, then join back together again.

***Note:** encodeForUrl appears to pass its string straight to Java, which means backslashes are treated as escape characters - `\b\n` encodes to `%08%0A` instead of `%5Cb%5Cn` - this behaviour is not part of standard URL encoding (nor CF strings in general). To avoid this use the function UrlEncodedFormat instead.*

**encodeForHTMLAttribute** is for placing dynamic text into a HTML attribute - it's purpose is to ensure the contents are treated as text (not parsed as HTML) - it doesn't know/care whether its contents is a URL or something else.

**In summary**, you probably want `encodeForHtmlAttribute( UrlEncodedFormat( Form.Path ) )` for this situation.

Comment: Correct. This normally means you url encode any parameters taken from the current url, and then html attribute encode the whole url.

Comment: Thanks peter for the valuable information. I would like to know inroder to use the encodeForUrl method in the JavaScript which package has to be imported?

Answer (score 1):

In your example the answer is to use both.

However, depending on the content of `FORM.path` you may break things.

The function `encodeForURL` should be called `encodeUriComponent` ([as is done in Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)) because it is intended to be used on uri components, not on the entire url string.  A uri component, such as name value pairs, need to be encoded separately otherwise the seperator ("=" for name value pairs) will be encoded as well.

The following will result in a 404, even if you have an `index.cfm` file.  Note that the path separator "/", query string separator "?" and name/value separator "=" are all encoded, making the entire string a single unit.

```
<a href="#encodeForURL("/index.cfm?x=y")#">here</a>
```

What should be done instead is:

```
<cfset pathURIEncoded = "/index.cfm?#encodeForURL("x")#=#encodeForURL("y")#">
<a href="#encodeForHTMLAttribute(Variables.pathURIEncoded)#">here</a>
```

Replacing `x` and `y` with variables and not static strings, of course.

Comment: encodeForUrl is not just for query strings (or name/value pairs) - it can be used anywhere in a url, so long as it's remembered that its purpose is to produce encoded text (and thus it deliberately changes delimiters). A simple example of non-qs use would be a directory based on a user name.

Comment: @PeterBoughton I have adjusted the text to not imply that uri components are limited to name value pairs.

Answer (score 0):

For this example, I would use the encodeForHTMLAttribute method as it is a static path.
The only exception would be if the value of the src attribute itself was generated from a publicly-accessible scope (sent via the URL, FORM etc) and contains dynamic data. If this was the case, I would use the encodeForURL() method.

Comment: let's say it's dynamic data.  Why would you suggest to use `encodeForURL()` instead of `encodeForHTMLAttribute()`?  Seems like you're implying that `encodeForURL()` is stronger?